# Randomization for pictureboxes

Tags: c#

Is it possible to populate the pictureBox 'actionbox1' with a random image of my choice?  Specifically, 'strollinstu' 'waterbottle' and 'goop?'  I've seen lots of questions but it's not really explained. Can someone explain how to do it?  I'm using a timer_tick event, if that helps.

Comment: Need a lot more info to answer this question.  What are the random images do you have them on your machine?  If its random how are you choosing.

Comment: They're in the resources.  They're called 'strollinstu' 'waterbottle' and 'goop'  And by random of my choice I mean specific images.

Comment: So you have three images as resources and you want one of them to show up in a picture box randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("name_of_your_image");` to get the image stream from the resources, use `Image.FromStream()` to load the image and then assign it to the `Image` property of the picture box. Just build a list with all your image names and then randomly pick one of those on each timer tick.

Example:

```
var imageNames = new List<string> { "strollinstu", "waterbottle", "goop" };

var rand = new Random();
var index = rand.Next(0, imageNames.Count - 1);

var s = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imageNames[index]);
actionbox1.Image = Image.FromStream(s);
```

Completely untested but should give you the idea.

Comment: I don't think I'm quite sure...                Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("testIMG"); is correct, I think, but how do you do the randomizing part?  I don't get it...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the example.  I just had a BSOD so I might not reply till tomorrow.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at WaterforMGC.gameform.randomizer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WaterforMGC\WaterforMGC\Form1.cs:line 251
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)  Didn't see null anywhere, so I have no idea.  But then again maybe I'm just tired :D

Comment: That means you did not get the manifest resource stream - you need to make sure that the image name you pass in matches exactly. Have a look here on how to access resources: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292